# Página PHP retornando HTTP/1.1 200 OK

Tags: php, html, apache

Após consulta SQL e retorno de dados usando JSON, utilizando o navegador **Firefox** é escrito o seguinte na tela:

```
0

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sun, 12 Jun 2016 22:52:42 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.28
Keep-Alive: timeout=5
Connection: Keep-Alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html

41
{"AQUI RETORNA O MEU":"JSON E ACABA"}
```

Utilizando o **Chrome Mobile** em um smartphone esses dados de HTTP não aparecem, retornando apenas o JSON como desejado.

Página de testes: www.megaprotecaoveicular.com.br/mobile/data.php

Agradeço a ajuda desde já.

Comment: Sem o código que faz o envio dessa mensagem não tem como a gente saber o que acontece.

Comment: cara que chato esse 0

Comment: jbueno, vou editar adicionando o código, mas antes funcionava normalmente com o mesmo código. E de tudo isso que ele retorna, somente o JSON é o que imprimi.

Comment: Opa! No navegador Chrome Mobile retornou somente o JSON, que era o pretendido. No Firefox para desktop continua mostrando os outros dados. Concluo então que o "erro" não é no código... Só por conhecimento, vocês fazem ideia do porquê isso acontece? '-'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cabeçalhos do *servidor* e não deveriam ser apresentados no lado *cliente*.

```
HTTP / 1.1 200 OK
```

Significa que o servidor está respondendo utilizando o protocolo HTTP versão 1.1. 200 é o código usado quando tudo está ok.

```
Content-Length: 0
```

O tamanho do conteúdo (neste caso 0 bytes)

```
Keep-Alive: timeout = 5, max = 100
```

Quanto tempo a conexão permanecerá aberta.

```
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

Informa que a conexão permanecerá aberta

```
Content-Type: text/plain
```

Qual é o tipo *MIME* do conteúdo (HTML, no caso, é: text/html)

[Documentação aqui (RFC 2616)](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html)

Informações mais compreensíveis com 23 links de referência: [HTTP Headers](https://pt.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lista_de_campos_de_cabe%C3%A7alho_HTTP)

**Motivo de estar aparecendo no lado cliente (navegador):** versão desatualizada do Mozilla Firefox. O erro foi relatado por diversos usuários no ano de 2011 e corrigido na versão 9 do navegador, ou pelo menos parou de apresentar o problema desde então.